# Why does Ipython keeps calling function from the old version of previously loaded module?

Tags: python, import, ipython

おはよう

Like in the topic: I have a M...odule (.py file) with a function F, which I import in Ipython. I constantly work on the function F (change and update it), so I make changes in .py file often.

Why when importing the module after changes are saved, Ipython does not see any changes, calls previously loaded version of the function, does not see any new functions in the module?

I have tried unimporting the module using `del M...odule` and then importing again, but this solution does not work. I also have tried deleting .pyc file before reimporting the M...odule, but It is not a valid solution neither.

Comment: Importing a module does not reload it, no.

Comment: Also see https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html